# If three quarters of the surface of a sphere is colored black, then an inscribed tetrahedron can be rotated so that all of its vertices are black

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> Let $P$ be a tetrahedron inside an sphere such that all of its vertices are on the surface of the sphere. Suppose that three quarters of sphere's surface is colored black. Show that there is a rotation of $P$ such that all of its vertices (when rotated) are black.

Clarifications from comments: The black region need not be connected, but must be measurable.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty standard, though it will require assumptions about area (e.g. assume that the colored surface is a closed set)

Comment: Does the black-colored surface portion have to be connected? Simply connected? Or something of that sort?

Comment: @ccorn It doesn't need to be connected. However, in order to tlk about surface area, it does need to be measurable.

Comment: @ccorn no connectedness assumption.

Comment: @CalvinLin Agrred. For sure it  is measurable.

Comment: Consider the group $SO(3)$ of rotations.
We have for subsets $A,B,C,D$ of $SO(3)$, determined by if they transport one wertex into the black set.
They have measure $\frac34$ (if we normalize the measure of $SO(3)$).
Thus in the worst case $\mu(A\cap B)=\frac12$, $\mu(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac14$ and $\mu(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)=0$ just barely. Any deviation from the worst case makes $\mu(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$ strictly positive and the intersection nonempty, which exactly states that there is a rotation making the tetrahedron all-black.
So the question is if such a deviation can be avoided.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: perhaps one can require the colored area to be closed. Intuitively I'd assume that this should ensure the existence of one possible rotation, even if the set of possible rotations has measure zero. Is this right? Drop, would such a requirement be acceptable?

Comment: @CalvinLin I've been searching online about this for a while, can you give me some reference? It is easy to see that in 2 dimensions, _any_ triangle needs the measure to be at least 2/3 for an arbitrary coloring to have a suitable rotation. I was hoping this changes in 3d because of the extra Dehn invariant... What do you think about that, would different shapes (of tetrahedra) have different minimal size for the black point set that forces the existence of a suitable rotation? Maybe a complete proof would shed some light into that but I haven't been able to fill in the gaps myself...

Comment: Is the tetrahedron regular?

Answer (score 2):

The problem as stated is **false**. However, by slightly adapting the conditions of the problem, we’re able to solve it by using [@Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen)’s approach.

To show falsehood, consider a sphere, divide it into octants, and paint all of them black, save for two opposite octants and their borders. By considering its symmetry group, it’s easy to show that any regular tetrahedron on this sphere will necessarily have a white vertex.

Nevertheless, the problem is true if *more than* $\frac34$ of the sphere is black. We can prove this as follows.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be the vertices of the tetrahedron, and let $R_A$, $R_B$, $R_C$, $R_D$ be the sets of rotations of the sphere that make their respective vertices black. If $\mu(X)$ denotes the measure of a set, recall that $$\mu(X\cap Y)\geq \mu(X)+\mu(Y)-1.$$ Since $\mu(R_A)=\mu(R_B)=\mu(R_C)=\mu(R_D)>\frac34$, applying this equation recursively, we obtain that $$\mu(R_A\cap R_B\cap R_C\cap R_D)>4\cdot\frac34-3=0.$$ In particular, the intersection of these sets must be non-empty, and there must exist a rotation that makes all vertices black, just as we wanted to prove. $\blacksquare$